# transitivity of subformula relation - proof

Tags: proof-verification, propositional-calculus

Problem: prove that the relation "is a subformula of" is transitive for propositional formulas.

let $\phi \in Sub(\psi)$ and $\psi \in Sub(\chi)$ prove that $\phi \in Sub(\chi)$.

my proof:

if $\phi \in Sub(\psi)$ then $\phi=\psi_i$ with $i\leq n$ (with $\psi_i$ a step of the formation sequence of $\psi$ and $\psi_n=\psi$)

if $\psi \in Sub(\chi)$ then $\psi=\chi_j$ with $j\leq m$ (with $\psi_j$ a step of the formation sequence of $\chi$ and $\psi_m=\psi$)

Then must be $\psi_i=\chi_k$ with $k\leq j$

So $\phi=\chi_k$ and $\phi \in Sub(\chi)$ $\square$

I was wandering whether my proof was correct and looking for a different proof which uses the recursive definition of subformula of a formula.

Comment: "Is a subformula of" is moreover a partial order on the set of all formulae.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always in these cases, we can apply induction on the "complexity" of the formula, i.e. on the number of occurrences of connectives, which amounts to follow the formation tree.

See **Definition 2.1.7** [page 12] for the definition of the set $Sub(\varphi)$ of subformulas  of $\varphi$.

*i) Basis :* If $\varphi$ is *atomic*, then  $Sub(\varphi)$ contains only $\varphi$; but the only subformula of $\varphi$ is $\varphi$ itself. Thus the subformulas of subformulas of $\varphi$ are subformulas of $\varphi$, and the property holds.

*ii) Induction step :* We have to consider the basic connectives : $\land$, $\lor$ and $\lnot$.

For $\land$, consider $\varphi := \varphi_1 \land \varphi_2$ :

> $Sub(\varphi_1 \land \varphi_2) = Sub(\varphi_1) \cup Sub(\varphi_2) \cup \{ \varphi_1 \land \varphi_2 \}$

and we assume that the property holds for $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$.

This means that if $\sigma \in Sub(\theta)$ and $\theta \in Sub(\varphi_i)$, then $\sigma \in Sub(\varphi_i)$.

Thus, if $\sigma \in Sub(\theta)$ and $\theta \in Sub(\varphi)$, we have two cases :

*a)* $\theta$ is $\varphi$ itself, and we are done; otherwise :

*b)* $\theta$ is a subformula of $\varphi_i$, in which case the induction hypotheses apply.

Comment: Do you think my proof was correct?

Comment: @alessandro - you have to review the details. The formation sequence $ψ_i, i≤n, ψ_n=ψ$ must be an "initial subsequence" of $χ_j, j≤m, χ_m=χ$. Thus : $ψ_i=χ_i, i≤n$. If $ϕ=ψ_i$, then $ϕ=χ_i$, and so we can conclude with : $ϕ∈Sub(χ)$.

Answer (score 1):

By Induction Principle(Theorem 1.1.3 on van Dalen's Logic and Structure) you can prove that $ \psi \in Sub(\phi) \implies Sub(\psi) \subset Sub(\phi) $, using the recursive definition of $ Sub $ function. The transitivity of $ \subset $ on sets do the rest.

Let $ \square $ be any connective and $ \neg $ the not symbol.

Let $ P(\phi) \iff  \forall \psi \in Sub(\phi)( Sub(\psi) \subset Sub(\phi) ) $.

(i) If $ \phi $ is atomic then $ \psi \in Sub(\phi)= \{\phi\} \iff \psi = \phi \iff Sub(\psi) = Sub(\phi) $.

(ii) Let $ P(\phi_{1}) $ and $ P(\phi_{2}) $, and let $ \psi \in Sub((\phi_{1}\square\phi_{2})) = Sub(\phi_{1})\cup Sub(\phi_{2}) \cup \{(\phi_{1}\square\phi_{2})\}  $, then $ \psi $ must be in one of these 3 sets.

If he's in the first by $ P(\phi_{1}) $ we have $ Sub(\psi) \subset Sub(\phi_{1}) \subset Sub((\phi_{1}\square\phi_{2})) $, if in the second we have the same, if in the third we have equality of the sets. We have then $ P((\phi_{1}\square\phi_{2})) $.

(iii) Let $ P(\phi) $, then if $ \psi \in Sub((\neg \phi)) = Sub(\phi)\cup \{ (\neg \phi)\} $, $ \psi $ must be in one of these 2 sets, again implying that $ Sub(\psi) \subset Sub((\neg\phi)) $, giving $ P((\neg \phi)) $.

By (i), (ii) and (iii) we have $ \forall \phi \in PROP \,\,P(\phi) $.